# Using Gorilla Mux endpoint to stream data via HTTP

Tags: rest, go, endpoint, flush, mux

After receiving a request on my REST endpoint, I would like to reply with status `200` and a body of data that is continuously generated and flushed (fetched from DB and can be very large). I'm looking for an effective way to do so with [Gorilla Mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux), since it's used all over the project.

I saw that it is possible with [Labstack Echo](https://github.com/labstack/echo), since it's `ResponseWriter` [supports](https://github.com/labstack/echo/blob/a028fd41fd30390b0e3e8f043c9893b9ea048b5d/response.go#L85) `http.Flusher` ([interface](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Flusher) to allow an HTTP handler to flush buffered data to the client). Unfortunately, it seems that gorilla's `ResponseWriter` does not support this.

---

Questions:

- Is there a way to have this behaviour with Gorilla Mux?
- If not, I'd appreciate a pointer to the 'slimmest' method to achieve this behaviour otherwise (I already found Labstack Echo, but perhaps there's a better method?)

Invariants:

- I cannot use `WebSockets` and should integrate the solution with the REST APIs.
- I will not be able to hold the entire file in the servers memory.

Comment: Gorilla's mux passes the ResponseWriter from the server through to the application.  Something else is going on if your app cannot get the http.Flusher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Flush in gorilla/mux because it is using `http.ResponseWriter` implementation from standard library. You are able to use `Flush` method by using this code below in your handler

```
func YourHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //SomeCode

    w.(http.Flusher).Flush()
}
```

Comment: I seemed to have overlooked that. Thanks, that solves the issue I had.

Comment: I am trying to stream response with a simple for loop. using time.sleep to simulate a delay for some reason its not streaming as i thought it would.


    https://gist.github.com/najamsk/7ec97d0a155653eed74c9fdcbf58a3a9

Comment: @NajamAwan Does it work as you expected if you add `w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")` at the beginning of your handler function?